# how to find text within a file using grep it hangs in terminal

Tags: grep, wc

I/m just playing around trying to hone my grep and pipe with other functions/commands. when I run grep to find a hash tag pipe it to get a count on it. The whole thing gets stuck in term like it is still looking for input when their are no more files in the directoy. how do I get it to exit 0 giving me back my prompt?

test file reads

```
#
hello # what is your name
```

results are

```
userx@voided & shit >> $  grep "#" | ls -l 
total 4
-rw-r--r-- 1 userx userx 29 Sep 26 08:26 testfile
^C

userx@voided & shit >> $  grep "#" | ls -l | wc -l > /dev/null
^C
userx@voided & shit >> $  grep "#" | ls -l | wc -l 
2
^C
userx@voided & shit >> $  grep "#" | ls 
testfile
^C
```

it is only one file that I have added the hash tag twice within that file put it into a directory then use this to get a count . after it returns it does not exit.

So now I'm wondering why, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: and why are you piping output from `grep` to `ls` ?

Comment: that was to feed it files. that was a  backwards thought now that you ask, and I think about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not giving `grep` any files to search.  Use

```
$ grep "#" testfile
```

or

```
$ grep "#" *
```

not simply

```
$ grep "#"
```

Comment: therefore using just the wildcard will search everything file within a directory ... sweet. ok thanks  ...